# Finding prime numbers between two limits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The number of prime numbers among $105!+2,105!+3,105!+4,...,105!+105$ ?
I tried to factorize like
$2^{101}×3^{50}×5^{25}×7^{17}×11^{9}×13^{8}×17^{6}×19^{5}×23^{4}×29^{3}×31^{3}×37^{2}×41^{2}×43^{2}×47^{2}×53×59×61×67×71×73×79×83×89×97×101×103$ ($251$ prime factors, $27$ distinct)
Now what to do?

Comment: This is derived from a (simple) proof that for every arbitrary value of $n$, there is a sequence of **at least** $n$ numbers which are **not** prime. Hence the answer to your question is obviously $0$ prime numbers.

Comment: I got it!Thank you @barakmanos!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the closed interval $[n! + 2, n! + n]$ lie only composite numbers. Namely
$k$ divides $n! + k$ for $k=2,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$n!+a$ is divisible by $a$ for $2\le a\le n$

For example :
$$105!+2=2\cdot \left(\frac{105!}{2}+1\right)\\105!+3=3\cdot \left(\frac{105!}{3}+1\right)\\~\\\cdots~\\~\\\\105!+105=105\cdot \left(\frac{105!}{105}+1\right)\\$$

Comment: Wow that was brilliant :-D!!Thank You!

Comment: Indeed it is pretty amazing when you think about it for the first time that arbitrarily large gaps can occur between consecutive primes!